# Create 2 tabs dynamically with different contents wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

The following code creates 2 tabs on the click of a button, but does not display any content. I'm still learning this and want to know what the mistake is.

Code behind

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popUp1.IsOpen = false;

    Canvas canvas4 = new Canvas();
    ScrollViewer viewer4 = new ScrollViewer();
    viewer4.Content = canvas4;

    string txtfl = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
    TextBlock txbl1 = new TextBlock();
    txbl1.Text = txtfl;
    canvas4.Children.Add(txbl1);

    TabItem newTab1 = new TabItem();
    newTab1.Header = "Text File";
    newTab1.Content = viewer4;
    tabctrl1.Items.Add(newTab1);

    tabctrl1.SelectedItem = newTab1;

    Brush br = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();
    canvas2.Background = br;
    ScrollViewer viewer2 = new ScrollViewer();
    viewer2.Content = canvas2;

    TabItem newTab2 = new TabItem();
    newTab2.Header = "Test";
    newTab2.Content = viewer2;
    tabctrl1.Items.Add(newTab2);
}
```

TabControl is created using XAML

XAML

```
<Window ... >
    <Grid>
        <Popup Name="popUp1" Width="500" Height="300" Placement="Center" IsEnabled="False" IsOpen="False">
            <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas1" Width="500"  Height="300" Visibility="Visible">
                <Button Content="Button" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,71,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Click="button2_Click" />                            
            </Canvas>
        </Popup>

        <TabControl Name="tabctrl1" Width="1345" Height="28" Margin="0,24,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="2">
            <TabControl.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF3A60AD" Offset="0.528"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6A85D8" Offset="0.01"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TabControl.Background>                   
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Provide canvas height and width. Then see what happens.

Comment: When coding up XAML elements, it is usually best to do it with the graphical editor first and look at the properties you need to include in your elements.

Comment: If you are learning WPF i would suggest completely forget any knowledge you had before about to build UIs and use the appropiate way. You are creating everything in codebehind, where you are better of using XAML. It would be helping if you post where your tabctrl1 is coming from. Also tools Like Snoop are a great way to learn how WPF build and layouts the controls.

Comment: your code seem to work just fine when I try it. Are you certain that the file you are reading has some content in it? It might also be easier to spot if the second tab is working as expected by changing the colour from white to one that would be more visible.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I tried, but there's no change.

Comment: @dowhilefor I've used XAML to create TabControl. the rest is written in the codebehind as I want the tabs to be created at run-time. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: @paul Yes, the file has some content. The reason I've used white as the background color is that the Window background color is different. The background color doesn't change to white in the second tab. So it's not working. If it's working, could you please post the complete XAML and codebehind?

Comment: @Ashwini If you want to create tabs dynamically then yes, but its to much to explain in a comment. It just revolves around the very basic foundation of WPF, DataBinding. A simple class you define, can be defined to be your tabs, and adding them to a collection(bound to the control) will automatically create your tab. Checkout ItemsControl and DataBinding in the MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the reason your code does not appear to work is because the Height of the tab control is set to 28.

Try changing it to 280, you should then be able to see the content.

```
  <TabControl Name="tabctrl1" Width="1345" Height="280" Margin="0,24,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="2">
```